# Pdf file in UIWebview with password

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I would like to specify the password of a PDF file in my request. Is this possible?
Currently my code is as following:

```cpp
NSString *nomPdf=_pdffile.name;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nomPdf ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url;
NSURLRequest *request;
if(path !=nil){
    url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
}
```

How can I pass the password string required of the PDF file in this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully an answer, but to rule out options, it [sounds like you can't](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3812698) embed the password as part of a URL.