# reading PDF protected by password using UIWebview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiwebview

I'm using this code to load my PDF into webView:

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/demo.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[viewWeb loadRequest:requestObj];
```

and everything works fine, but there's one problem to resolve.

My **demo.pdf** is protected by **password**, of course I know this password but don't want to input it everytime when pdf is loaded.

Can I set my password as variable/string and load **PDF** without type password?

Comment: hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519122/pdf-file-in-uiwebview-with-password especially http://forums.adobe.com/message/3812698

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything as straight forward as telling the webview what the password is, but instead I would download the PDF file manually (NSURLConnection or something), then unlock it using CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(doc, pass).

You could then generate an unlocked version as NSData in memory and load that into the web view (not password protected at this point)

You can draw it into NSData using the following (skip over the parts about custom drawing a red box on top):
http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/drawing-over-a-pdf-in-ios-pdf-template

Of course if your PDF is huge or has a ton of images this could take some time...

CGPDFDocument reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGPDFDocument/Reference/reference.html