# Load Password Protected PDF in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

I am loading a PDF file in `UIWebView`. The PDF file is password protected.
But I don't want the `UIWebView` to prompt for a password. I already have password stored in my database. So I want to implicitly provide the password to `UIWebView` and load the PDF document without prompting the user for password.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519122/pdf-file-in-uiwebview-with-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [PDFKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit) and display your PDF with a `PDFView`instead of a `UIWebView` which is deprecated. `PDFDocument` has an [unlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436033-unlock) method. So you can display protected documents without displaying a password prompt.

**Edit:** PDFKit only available as of iOS 11. For older iOS versions you may draw the PDF with Core Graphics and [`CGPDFDocument`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpdfdocument) (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758774/2352344). I would use the PDFKit for iOS 11 and only for the older iOS versions Core Graphics.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, PDFView requires minimum deployment target of iOS 11. I want to support iOS 9 and above.

Comment: @Nirav: I've extended my answer,